# Есть ли в phpstorm горячие клавиши для добавления jsdocs?

Tags: phpstorm, hotkeys, jsdoc

Прошу прощения за, возможно, нелепый вопрос, но я не могу найти горячие клавиши для добавления конструкции документирования кода в этой IDE. Есть ли комбинация для установки такой конструкции:

```
/**
* 
**/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Enter` после `/**` добавляет JSDoc комментарий с соответствующими тегами.
Можно назначить шорткат для **Settings | Keymap | Other | Fix doc comment**, чтобы создавать эту конструкцию по нажатию горячих клавиш